# Monitoring of Windows RDP farm with nagios

Tags: 16.04, windows, rdp, nagios3

I'd like to have a somewhat specific custom check to monitor Windows remote desktop server farms with nagios (nagios3 on ubuntu 16.04)

Specifically, I'd like to have a WARNING state if any of the servers has a value different from the default 100 in the "relative weight of server in the farm" setting, and a CRITICAL state if the "participate in connection broker load balancing" is unchecked as well as if the user login mode is set to anything else than "Allow all connections" (i.e., "Allow reconnections, but prevent new logons" or "Allow reconnections, but prevent new logons until the server is restarted").

I'd absolutely prefer a solution that relies as much as possible on standard repository stuff on the Ubuntu side (nsclient++ is running on the  Windows boxes) ...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a plugin for Nagios that allows it to monitor windows servers running RDP services

http://troels.arvin.dk/code/nagios/check_x224

Its not quite a complete solution but it shows how to do it with other similar data from the RDP server so it should just be case of changing the fields requested

Answer (score 0):

I've done something similar but with Pandora FMS. Maybe my procedure can help you in Nagios. I have an agent collecting the data of a log in my Windows Server and I have set alerts when the text collected matches with "WARNING" or "CRITICAL". If you can do something similar in Nagios, collect the data in your Windows and send it to Nagios.

Comment: I checked it: Changing the "Allow all connection" or the relative weight percentage from the GUI does not create an event log entry